# Запятая в выражении "в точности как показано на рисунке"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед союзом "как"?

Насколько я понимаю, если бы использовалось наречие "точь-в-точь", то по правилам запятая была бы лишней. Но здесь используется наречие "в точности", поэтому возникли сомнения.

Гугл выдает примеры с запятой и без.

Мне кажется, что запятая не нужна, но хотелось бы в этом удостовериться.

**Правка:**
Целиком предложение выглядит так:
*Помните, что схема SQL по-прежнему ничего не знает о наследовании - таблицы выглядят в точности как показано на рис. 1.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*В точности* ничем не хуже *точь-в-точь*... )))

[ЗАПЯТАЯ НЕ СТАВИТСЯ,](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

> если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание НЕ или частицы
> СОВСЕМ, СОВЕРШЕННО, ПОЧТИ, ВРОДЕ, ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ, ИМЕННО, ПРОСТО,
> например: *Волосы у нее вьются точь-в-точь как у матери.*

Другой источник, приводя перечень частиц, отменяющих запятую, упоминает: [И ДРУГИЕ](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=264)!

> ...если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание **не** или
> частицы **совсем, совершенно, почти, вроде, точь-в-точь, именно,
> просто и др.**: *Да он всё делает не как люди* (М. Г.); *Стало светло
> почти как днем;* *Он выглядел совершенно (совсем) как ребенок.*

*Эти люди выглядят в точности как голливудские знаменитости.*

Answer (score 2):

Здесь контекст нужен побольше, так не ответишь, давайте всю фразу.

Но из общих соображений я бы эту запятую не ставил.
По большому счету любой список частиц, после которых не ставится запятая перед *"как"*, не является исчерпывающим, там всегда есть "и т. д.". И *"в точности"* вполне в это "и т. д." попадает.

Если это не убедительно, то надо посмотреть, не выступает ли эта конструкция в роли обстоятельства при глаголе "поступайте в точности как показано на рисунке" (ср. "делай как я!"). В этом случае без запятой вполне можно - и как правило нужно - обойтись.

Но если там вполне законный сравнительный оборот то запятая требуется если не перед "как", то перед "в точности" - это уже надо всю фразу иметь.

Гугл в таких вопросах - инструмент довольно сомнительный сам по себе, а тут еще такой момент, что, даже имея содержательную выборку примеров, можно пропустить принципиальную разницу случаев, для которых применяется разная пунктуация. Возможно, вы в эту ловушку и попали.